# Lambda Expression compare strings

Tags: compare, expression

I have a workable code with `StartsWith`, but I need to use `Compare` instead of `StartsWith`:

```
LambdaExpression startsWithLambda = (Expression<Func<string, string, bool>>)((x, s) => x.StartsWith(s)); // works
//  LambdaExpression startsWithLambda = (Expression<Func<string, string, bool>>)((x, s) => string.Compare(x,s) > 0); -  doesn't work

MethodInfo startsWithMI = (startsWithLambda.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;

ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
Expression nameProp = Expression.Property(param, _propertyName);

Expression filteredOk = Expression.Constant(true);

Expression startsWithStringExpr = Expression.Constant(_filter);
Expression startsWithCondition = Expression.Call(nameProp, startsWithMI, startsWithStringExpr);

filteredOk = Expression.AndAlso(filteredOk, startsWithCondition);

Expression<Func<T, bool>> where = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(filteredOk, new ParameterExpression[] { param });

var result = orderedQuery.Where(where).Take(_linesCount);
```

How to implement `string.Compare` with a lambda expression?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
  Expression startsWithCondition = Expression.Call(startsWithMI, nameProp, startsWithStringExpr);

If use static method parameters in Call method should be switched.